# Draw samples of defined size until list is empty. Size of last draw

Tags: python, random

I have a list of numbers `mylist` and want to draw from this list samples of size `pair_size`. The drawing of sample continues until `mylist` is empty.

> My challenge is ensuring that the last sample can also only be of size `pair_size`

My code works but is rather lengthy and complicated.

So my question is: **How can I improve my solution to make it (i) more readable and (ii) also work for non consecutive `pair_size`?**

```
import random

mylist = list(range(10000))
pair_size = [5,6,7]
pairs = []

while len(mylist) > (pair_size[0] + pair_size[-1]):

    n = random.choice(pair_size)
    pairs.append(mylist[:n])
    mylist = mylist[n:]

    if len(mylist) in pair_size: 

         pairs.append(mylist)

    else:

        if (len(mylist) - pair_size[0]) in pair_size:
            l1,l2 = mylist[:pair_size[0]], mylist[pair_size[0]:]
            pairs.append(l1)
            pairs.append(l2)
        elif (len(mylist) - pair_size[-1]) in pair_size:
            l1,l2 = mylist[:pair_size[-1]], mylist[pair_size[-1]:]
            pairs.append(l1)
            pairs.append(l2)
        elif (len(mylist) - pair_size[1]) in pair_size:
            l1,l2 = mylist[:pair_size[1]], mylist[pair_size[1]:]
            pairs.append(l1)
            pairs.append(l2)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Pair_size must contain consecutive numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

mylist = list(range(20))
pair_size = [5,6,7]
pairs = []
min_size = min(pair_size)

while len(mylist) >= min_size:
    n = random.choice(pair_size)
    if len(mylist) >= n:
        pairs.append(mylist[:n])
        mylist = mylist[n:]
pairs.append(mylist) # optional

print(pairs)
```

Comment: This solution does not work. Given the last pair may end up being of size not in `pair_size`

Comment: that's why that line is optional. do you really need all members of mylist in pairs can you ignore last few ? What happens when it is not possible to completely use mylist elements?

Comment: But I need to be able to draw all list members. If this is mathematically not possible for some combinations the only options would be to determine this before hand and change `mylist`